# max4node max device not returning sound back to ableton? (Ableton Live 10)

Tags: ableton-live, max-msp

I have found a library called `max4node`, which connects nodejs code to Ableton Live via Max4Live.  Fantastic... and it works somewhat on and off... while I am debugging that, I want to fix the Max device to not just control Ableton, but also allow audio fed into the device to be fed back to my speakers...

When I enabled max4node device on a track, I can control Ableton Live 10 (when it works) via these NodeJS calls.. BUT I cannot hear anything from that track... defeating the purpose of the device altogether

do I just leave a blank track off to the side to attach this device to?  Or is there a way to add `pluginOut~` so the audio can be propogated back into Live itself??

[image]

code for the plugin is found at : https://github.com/alpacaaa/max4node

Code I am triggering trying to get this to work :

```
var Max4Node = require('max4node');

var max = new Max4Node();
max.bind();

console.log("bind returned")

max.call({
    path: 'live_set tracks 0 clip_slots 2 clip',
    method: 'fire'
});

console.log("fired a clip")

max.count({
    path: 'live_set tracks 0',
    property: 'clip_slots'
}).once('value', function(count) {
    console.log(count + ' clips');
    return;
});

console.log("Done.")
```

My output, failing to show the clip count.... and not firing either..

```
% node test_max_connect.js
bind returned
fired a clip
Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after finding the debugger in Max.. I can see now the console reading that it cannot find the `main.js` which makes total sense as I had moved the device to an area I thought I would be able to find it easier later!  So it's just a hard coded string I will fix

for others who find issues like this, here is the console that helped me

Step 1 : create a MIDI track and drag the device into the effects area like any Max device.  Then click that yellow button on the right, to edit the device.

[image]

Next, you can open the Max Console .. it's the button on the right hand side with a hamburger menu looking icon

[image]

Here it is again, opened

[image]